# Как сделать событие по клику кнопки? PyQt5 + Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Есть 2 кнопки, и есть 2 скрипта автотеста. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку отрабатывался скрипт? Вот пример кнопок.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication

class AutoTestWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        btn1 = QPushButton("Тест № 1 ", self)
        btn1.move(30, 50)

        btn2 = QPushButton("Тест № 2", self)
        btn2.move(150, 50)

        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.statusBar()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Запуск тестов')
        self.show()
```

Вот пример скрипта

```
def findelem(driver, query):
    driver.get("https://www.yandex.ru/")
    try:
        box = driver.wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.ID, "text")))
        button = driver.wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.CLASS_NAME, "search2__button")))
        box.send_keys(query)
    suggestion_box = driver.wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                                       "body > div.i-bem.popup.suggest2.suggest2_theme_flat.suggest2_size_m.suggest2_adaptive_yes.suggest2_type_advanced.suggest2_ahead_yes.popup_adaptive_yes.popup_animate_no.popup_autoclosable_yes.popup_theme_ffffff.suggest2-detect_js_inited.suggest2_js_inited.popup_js_inited.popup_to_bottom.popup_visibility_visible")))


try:
    button.click()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сигналу нужно создать функцию и вызывать в ней `findelem`, например:

```
def buttonClicked(self):
    driver = self.driver  # Например, драйвер будет в поле AutoTestWindow
    query = self.line_edit_query.text()  # А запрос будет в виджете

    findelem(driver, query)
```

Если кнопок несколько, то для каждой сделать свою функцию-обработчик

---

Кроме того, в `initUI(self):` лучше каждый виджет добавить как поле т.е. будет `self.btn1`, `self.btn2`, иначе только при выполнении `initUI` будет доступ в коде к объектам тем кнопкам